# JQuery Modal Dialog not disabling page IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I was using jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js on my page, and when displaying a modal dialog it would disable the page perfectly making you "Cancel" or Escape out of the dialog to re-enable the page.  Unfortunately this ui version was not compatible with JQuery's Sortable() functionality, so i upgraded to the newest stable version of jquery-ui-1.10.3, which solved the sortable issue, but now won't disable the page on a modal.  My dialog is created with;

```
NOT_AVAILABLE_ALERT = $("#modalMessageAlert").dialog(
            {
                position: "center",
                resizable: false,
                bgiframe: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 250,
                height: 130,
                draggable: false,
                modal: true,
                close:function(event,ui){
                    },
                open:function(event,ui){
                    }
                }
            );
        $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').each(function(){
            $(this).text("Unavailable");
            $(this).css("width","235px");
        });
```

within the document.ready() function, and opened with

```
NOT_AVAILABLE_ALERT.dialog("open");
```

which opens fine as well.  The HTML to the dialog is as follows, anyone know if this is a known issue with this new version, or a reason this might be happening?
Thank you!

```
<div id="modalMessageAlert" style="left:-200px; display:none">
    <h3>This feature is not available in this demo household.</h3>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <input type="image" src="/applications/Images/close_on.gif" Value="Close" onclick="NOT_AVAILABLE_ALERT.dialog('close');"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you upgraded you css to 1.10.3 too?

Comment: i have custom CSS written for the functionality and layout of the dialogs themselves, but have updated the main jquery-ui.css and it still persists.  I just want the page to gray out and disable like in the previous version of JQuery-ui I was using.